# Can you return type tiberius::QueryResult from function that uses Sql Client?

Tags: rust

When trying to return `tiberius::QueryResult` I am unable to do so because it references data owned. How do I return `stream` if this is now allowed?

```
pub async fn sql_conn(str_query: &str) -> std::result::Result<tiberius::QueryResult<'_>, tiberius::error::Error>{
    let mut config = Config::new();
    config.host("host");
    config.port(1433);
    config.authentication(AuthMethod::sql_server("usr", "pw"));
    config.trust_cert();

    let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
    tcp.set_nodelay(true)?;

    let mut client = Client::connect(config, tcp.compat_write()).await?;

    let stream = client.query(
        str_query
        , &[]).await?;

    Ok(stream)
}
```

Error:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `client`

returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because your query result object references your client and depends on resources that it uses.  Most likely, that's because your query result is streaming and the client owns the connection required for that streaming to occur.

Rust won't let you return the query result because it needs the client and the client, as a local variable, is destroyed when the function returns, since it goes out of scope.  If Rust let you return the query result, it would likely reference the closed client, and your program would either fail or segfault.  This is a common problem in many languages that don't provide garbage collection, and Rust is specifically designed not to allow you to make this mistake.

There are a couple of options here.  First, you can create a function which creates the SQL connection and returns a client, then use the client and the query results it returns in the function where you want the data.  That way, both the client and the query results will have the right lifetimes.

You could also try to create a struct which instantiates and holds your client and then use that to make the query.  For example (untested):

```
struct Connection<'a> {
    client: tiberius::Client<'a>
}

impl<'a> Connection<'a> {
    fn query(&mut self, query: &str) -> Result<tiberius::QueryResult<'a>, tiberius::error::Error> {
        client.query(str_query, &[]).await
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same as the first situation, just with a different structure.

The third option is to both instantiate the client and totally consume the results in the same function, and then return some structure (like a Vec) with the results.  This means that you will have to consume the entirety of the data, which you may not want to do for efficiency reasons, but it does solve the lifetime issue, and depending on your scenario, may be a valid option.